# mutating nested state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

lets say my initial state looks like this:

`state = { body: [] }`

Later on after some changes has been made (its a drag and drop app, i want to save the structure of current dom to state to be able to load the same structure later)

```
state = {
 body: [
   {
     type: 'section',
     options: [],
     content: [
       {
         type: 'column',
         options: [],
         content: null
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     type: 'section',
     options: []
   }
 ]
}
```

As you can see it might have multiple nested elements which is not ideal but my question is how can I dynamicaly update state properly? Using spread opreator would be hard (i think) because I dont know how many levels of nested state there will be.

When something happen like an element is moved to a different section or someing is moving in a section I would update my locations of elements like this:

```
currentState = this.state.body;
newState = currentState.slice();
//here im updating what ever I want in newState array like swapping elements
this.setState({body: newState})
```

Would it work or there is much better solution for this? An array would have new reference but what about objects within the array?

Comment: You can use object.assign instead of slice, everything will be cloned.

Comment: TC that a huge state object is problematic.

Comment: @Antoine So how would go approach that type of problem?

Comment: Your solution is fine unless the state is huge, is it a big object ~= 10kb or just deeply nested ? In case it was huge I would recommend removing it from the state and refactor your code to chunk your state into pages for example.

Comment: into pages? Can you give me an example? As for my example every object in a body array is a new section and that section can have another dom element and can be nested multiple times.